# Add class to comment in Genesis

Tags: wordpress, genesis

I have a custom callback that's rebuilding the comment list, and I used some of the default options from Genesis including:

```
<li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
```

How do I add an additional class? When I just try to add it at the end of this `<li>`, it doesn't work. But I want to also include all the default classes that come from `comment_class();`

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, you can just add a class name into the `comment_class('test-class');` function